# create tunnel in order to access https via port 443

Tags: putty, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have Windows machine that connected to Linux server **192.9.100.10**

And Linux server has connectivity to the IBM blade center management GUI - **192.9.100.200**

From my Windows machine I **do not** have connectivity to **192.9.100.200**

My target is to access the IBM management center as **https://192.9.100.200:443**

So I do the following steps:

- I use the PuTTY and create a tunnel from the Linux server to the IBM blade center management VIA port **443**
- In the forward port in the PuTTY I set that putty

  ```
   L1000               192.9.100.200:443
  ```
- After this setting I verified the port 443 as the following from the cmd window ( on the WIN machine )

  ```
   telnet 192.9.100.200 443
  ```

... and I get telnet connection successfully

- But when I try to access the IBM management center by http as
  https://192.9.100.200:443
  then I do not get any connection (white screen)

Can someone help me to understand what the problem here?

How to debug and how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Your question fits better for superuser.com rather than SO.

Answer (score 2):

> L1000               192.9.100.200:443

Means you created a tunnel from 1000 port on your Windows machine.
From this machine you have to connect via https://127.0.0.1:1000/ to use this tunnel.

If that won't work you may also try to change the "Auto" mode to "IPv4".

Comment: hi , why http and not https?

Comment: still not have connection when I set it as https ? what chuld be other ?

Answer (score 0):

Some time your window firewall also give some trouble, try to turn off your window machine firewall and try to  browse once again,

As sometime **window firewall** block inbound request

I also suggest you to see the application **access.log**  and **error.log** file which is listening to 443, these file will help you to figure out the problem